# NameError: name 'glob' is not defined

Tags: python

```
#coding=utf 
import glob
glob.glob('/pycharm/*')
```

I used to the python3.5 version , 
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

```
#coding=utf
from glob import *
glob('/pycharm/*')
```

It has another error,
`NameError: name 'glob' is not defined`

Comment: sorry mate input error but the error is really existence

Comment: just run `import glob` and check whether it runs without error or not

Comment: this is true and i was check it

Comment: it imports or not?

Comment: it's true just run import glob

Comment: Where is your glob.py file? Probably python does not see it

Comment: Is the file you created named `glob.py`?

Answer (score 4):

If you just need `glob()` makes sure that the function name is the same as a module name. This worked for me.

```
from glob import glob
g = glob('*.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check if "glob" is used as a variable in the code, before the import statement is called.

if "glob" is used as a variable, the original meaning of the module will change, giving the mentioned errors.

Comment: glob here is actually referred to package. So "import glob" will work. i tried on my end

Answer (score 0):

If you can import this package in terminal, maybe you should check if you import glob before call it or not.I met this error today in a jupyter notebook, find I forget to run the import sentence XD

Answer (score 0):

you need to add full path
like this

```
import glob
covid_path = r'C:\Users\Mohmed\Desktop\Corona Project\new start\CNN\CT_COVID'
covid_files = glob.glob(covid_path + '/*')
print(len(covid_files))
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to install the glob module in your machine by the following command
`$ pip install glob2`

and after the installation, you just need to do the following changes in your code

```
import glob2

g = glob2.glob('/pycharm/*')
```

Or you can import only the glob module from the glob2 for the better performance

```
from glob2 import glob
g = glob2.glob('/pycharm/*')
```